# Can you say "table is full of something"?

Tags: word-usage

I have a question whether you can use the phrase "table is full of something."

When a family is celebrating their son's birthday with many of the foods the son likes on the table, can you say this?

The table is full of his favorite foods.

I found some sentences on the Internet which include the phrase "table is full of ..." but I am not sure if you can say it because I think "full of ..." is often used with an enclosed space (the box is full of toys), not an open space like on top of the table.

Comment: I think "full" is used here as an idiom, similar to how a restaurant is 'full' – not actually a volume filled to the ceiling with human bodies, rather all the available seating is occupied. It is 'at capacity'. "Full of" is also used when there is more of a quantity of something than usual: "Cookie full of raisins", "book full of gangsters", "That liar is full of (excrement)." – again not the literal meaning of a volume filled to the top, but evoking that idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Full of*** is a synonym of ***loaded with*** ([PowerThesaurus](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/full_of/synonyms)), and as such, some may argue that it can describe a table in this way.

Yet I agree that there are better ways of saying this, of which one is the synonym I just mentioned:

> The table is ***loaded with*** his favorite foods [maybe *dishes* is
> better].

***Covered in food*** is also an option.

This [GNgram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=table+full+of+food%2C+table+loaded+with+food%2Ctable+covered+in+food%2Ctable+loaded+with+foods%2Ctable+covered+in+foods&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctable%20full%20of%20food%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctable%20loaded%20with%20food%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctable%20covered%20in%20food%3B%2Cc0) did not find any instance of these expressions being used with *food* in the plural. However, if you leave ***food*** in the singular, the expression ***table full of food*** is actually the most common:

[image]

*Loaded with* or *covered in* are more formal phrases.

Comment: Maybe not with *foods*, but we can find other examples, like [table full of sweets](https://books.google.com/books?id=OpPsCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT217&dq=%22table+full+of%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjCyKGFpvTxAhUCXc0KHcMjBwcQ6AEwAXoECAMQAg), or the singular [table full of food](https://books.google.com/books?id=dS3YCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT83&dq=%22table+full+of%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjJ5oKtpvTxAhVgGFkFHbL6CL04FBDoATAHegQIBBAC).

Comment: Agreed. With "food" in the singular it is actually the most common expression. Will add this in my answer.